# Color palette conversion like in XTerm

Tags: algorithm, colors

In `xterm` we can have 256, 88 or 16 colors. I was wondering, is there an algorithm that can get color from 256 color chart and find the match / equivalent color in 88 color chart?

Moreover, is there an algorithm that can convert color from 256 color chart to a color from 16 color chart?

For example: if the color is `#00D700` (Light Green) -> `#00FF00` (Light Green in 16 color chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Color quatization

In computer graphics, [color quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) or color image quantization is a process that reduces the number of distinct colors used in an image, usually with the intention that the new image should be as visually similar as possible to the original image.

## Posterization

This process is used in the [Posterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization) of an image, which entails conversion of a continuous gradation of tone to several regions of fewer tones, with abrupt changes from one tone to another, originally done with photographic processes to create posters.

[image]

## Algorithms

The process you are describing, to create a palette with fewer but similar colors than the original, falls in to this category despite not exactly being an image. You will find lots of possible implementations of this algorithm as either 'posterization' or 'quantization'.

The most popular algorithm by far for color quantization and palette optimization, invented by [Paul Heckbert](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ph/) in 1980, is the [**median cut algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_cut).

You can find Java examples in [this site from the University of Illinois](http://www.cs.uic.edu/bin/view/CS101/Code)